# How long does a page alive while sending multiple mails simultaneously?

Tags: php, csv, email

I have a CSV file which contains for example 50 different mails in 50 rows. When I import the file, I need to read that mails one by one and store mails in the database and then send some contents to every each of them.
I'll implement that functionality with php mail function.

The problem is for sending that multiple mails, would it exceed the maximum loading time? Would it crash the page? If so, are there any other ways to achieve my requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the PHP setting `max_execution_time`. Depending on the configuration, you can set it via an [INI file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) or via [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

However, I think that the `mail()` function does not require a lot of time. Afaik, the mail is just given to the MTA (and added to a queue), and the MTA does the rest for you. So you should be fine and your PHP script should not cancel due to the max execution time.